In Vue 3, make the properties of the encapsulated component accessible and enable IDE autocomplete support
I have a vue3 component MyButton and it's a decoration of vuetify v-btn component.
I want MyButton props to extend all of the props v-btn has, and get autocomplete support from IntelliJ or VSCode, is there a way to achieve it?
Currently, the below code works well for passing props from MyButton to VBtn except I cannot get any autocomplete function in Intellij or VScode.
<template>
  <v-btn v-bind="$attrs">
    <slot />
  </v-btn>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

defineComponent({
  name: 'MyButton',
});
</script>


Try Instaling Vue - Offical Vscode plugin. It worked for me
